# Google reCaptcha changing hl depending on php if statement

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I have a wordpress site.

My site has 5 languages which is determined via this variable `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` - I use this in my php files to change what is displayed depending on the language the user has selected.

The site has a contact form bundled with it which I can edit via a php file. The form includes a v2 `Google reCaptcha`. The language of the reCaptcha question is automatic - but it does not work very well.

For example if a person is in Spain the language is Spanish even if they are Dutch and in my Dutch area of the website and there is no way to change this as a website user.

I have edited the code so that the default behaviour is in English via adding `hl=en` to the line below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en&onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

However I want to change the parameter for the `hl` depending on what language my website user has chosen to read the site in. I know I can't simply put the script in a php if statement like this one;

```
<?php   if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ) {     ?>
```

becasue the scripts are loaded by the browser - how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to review the appropriate langguage codes that google accepts and then adjust your code accordingly so you can send the correct parameter. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language

Then you will simply write the following:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<?php $ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;?>&onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>`

You php will render the page with the user chosen language in place of 'en'. But again, your `$ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` variable must output exactly what google expects or it will not work.

Comment: Thanks colecmc. I tried that but it didn't work - it reverted to the default Google behaviour. It could be because the $ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE; is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This code works a treat. Thanks colecmc for the structure. This code slightly changes the way the WPML parameter is called. Now the Google reCapcha generates in whatever language a website user has chosen to view the site in.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE; ?>&onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```